# t-butyl VS s-butyl

Tags: nomenclature

In the IUPAC system the common names for t-butyl and s-butyl are still accepted. Usually the "t" from tert- and the "s" of sec- is not included in the alphabetic ordering of substituents. If you have both these substituents on a hydrocarbon, which will get alphabetic preference in the ordering of the name? Does it matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***sec-* has priority over *tert-*, but the use of *sec-* should be avoided.**

The [2013 IUPAC Blue Book](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/eBook/978-0-85404-182-4) has this to say:

> **P-14.5.3** When an alphanumerical ordering is required and Roman letters do not permit a decision for the order of citation, italicized letters are considered.

The text and examples are essentially unchanged from those of the 2004 Provisional Recommendations, which are [freely available](http://old.iupac.org/reports/provisional/abstract04/favre_310305.html#ct). Three examples are provided, one of which happens to be 1-*sec*-butyl-3-*tert*-butylbenzene:

[image: 1-sec-butyl-3-tert-butylbenzene]

However, the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) of this molecule is given as 1-(butan-2-yl)-3-*tert*-butylbenzene. An alternative name is 3-*tert*-butyl-1-(1-methylpropyl)benzene.

(Actually, the 2013 Recommendations do explicitly say that this molecule is *not* to be called 1-*sec*-butyl-3-*tert*-butylbenzene, but by one of the other two names instead. This is because the name *sec*-butyl is no longer retained. The 2004 draft, though, does explicitly place the *sec-* alphabetically before the *tert-*.)