# Sec-butyl vs Butyl - Alphabetizing and Ordering in Alkane Nomenclature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

For the structure below,

[image]

if we use trivial name for complex substituent, do we call it
5-butyl-10-*sec*-butyltetradecane, or
5-*sec*-butyl-10-butyltetradecane?

Considering that both substituent are placed in a symmetrical way in the parent chain and *sec*- prefix are not included in alphabetizing, which one is preferred?

Comment: Note that the prefix _sec_-butyl was still contained in the 1993 IUPAC recommendations but is no longer recommended in the current (2013) recommendations.

Comment: Related: [t-butyl VS s-butyl](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/84709/7951)

Answer (score -2):

This may be resolved by IUPAC Rule [A-2.3(ii)](https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_36.htm) which says "The name of a complex radical is considered to begin with the first letter of its complete name," which seems to suggest to me "sec-butyl" is considered to start with "s" and not "b" in this case.  As I interpret Rule A-2.3(i) it is only *multiplying prefixes* (di-, tri-) which are ignored when alphabetizing substituent names.

Comment: but as far as i understand, sec, tert prefixes are not used for alphabetizing as well as the multiplying prefixes. only iso prefix is included in alphabetizing. pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: this problem wont occur if we change the sec-butyl to 1-metylpropyl, thus the name will become 5-butyl-10-(1-metylpropyl)tetradecane